# smarty error on foreach loop on if else

Tags: php, smarty

I am getting this syntax error, though it all seems ok.

```
{/if}" unclosed {else} tag
```

This is the code in a .tpl file. If a take out the foreach loop the code compiles fine.

Please advise.

```
    <div >
    {if $ct_messages == 0}
        <h4 class="account_notice">
            Aucun message dans votre boîte de réception.
        </h4>
    {else}
            <button class="btn check_all" type="button" value="0" > Tout sélectionner</button>
            <div class="message_options">
                <button id="message_delete" class="btn btn_box" type="button" > Supprimer </button>
            </div>
            <form action="" name="delete_message" method="post" id="delete_message" >
                <table>
                    {foreach $messages as $message}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="hide_id"> { $message['message_id']} </td>
                            <td class="mess_info1" ><input type="checkbox" name="message_id[]" value= "{$message['message_id']}" ></td>
                            <td {if isset($message['opened'])} class="not_read" {else} class="read" > {$message['subject']} </td>
                            <td {if isset($message['opened'])} class="not_read" {else} class="read"> {$message['time_sent']} </td>
                        </tr>
                    {/foreach}
                </table>
            </form>
    {/if}

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually missing two `{/if}` closing tags. This is how it should look like in both instances:

```
{if isset($message['opened'])} class="not_read" {else} class="read" {/if}
```